# single document in same collection Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I build a quiz app and i use firestore for the data, i need a code for this : when the user select answer 1 he goes to page A , but when he select answer 2 he goes to page B ... etc

This is where am i : *all the answers go to the same page when i tap on it, i want for every answer has his own page*

[image]

This is my code :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class question14 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _question14State createState() => _question14State();
}

class _question14State extends State<question14> {
  int selectedIndex 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('numberzz').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading ...');
              return ListView.builder(

                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                itemExtent: 200.0,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot document =
                      snapshot.data.documents[index];

                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 300.0, 0.0, 450.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: selectedIndex == index
                          ? EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
                          : EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                      title: Image.network(
                        document['number'],
                      ),
                      selected: selectedIndex == index,
                      onTap: () {
                        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                          DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
                              await transaction.get(document.reference);
                          await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
                            'vote': freshSnap['vote'] + 1,
                          });
                        });
                        Navigator.push(
                                context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => new page()));

                        setState(() {
                          selectedIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: Okay, so what does your code do so far?  Are having troubles with the display? With the code meeting the homework assignment requirements?

Comment: for now my actuel code let me select one item and redirect for the same page, i want for every item his own page  ..  when user tap on number " 1 "  he goes to page " A  " , when he tap on number " 2" he goes to another page " B ", when user tap on number " 3 " he goes to page " C ".

Answer (score 0):

You can check which index is selected before navigating. Kind of conditional navigation.

```
switch(selectedIndex){
 case 0:
   Navigator.of(context).push(.....(Page A));
   break;
 case 1:
  .......
  break;
```

I think you get the point.
But this code should come after

```
setState(() { selectedIndex = index };
```

Comment: i edited my first post by changing the gif to explain more what i need,
thank you for your concern !